# Android: Execution failed for task ":app:dexDebug"

Tags: android, gradle

I have a problem with my Android Studio Project, it compiled fine and I don't know what I did that break it.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Moritz\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Moritz\AndroidStudioProjects\Expenses1\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Moritz\AndroidStudioProjects\Expenses1\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       1

build.gradle (module: app)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'

compile ('com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.4')
compile ('com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0')
compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3'
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.0.6'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
compile 'com.github.m1s73r:LolliPin:v1.3'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9'
compile 'net.objecthunter:exp4j:0.4.5'
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had same problem on clean android sdk(android Studio bundle).

Try to run from command line from project root

```
./gradlew.bat clean assembleDebug
```

Please attach logs.

Also could be helpful run `gradlew` in verbose mode.

Comment: Thank you so much! Altough your answer didn't build it, it showed me the real cause of the problem. I remember updating my Java version and your command suggested that the Java Path wasn't set. So I set my "JAVA_PATH" and added the java/bin folder to the path variable, it's now working perfectly. You are my hero! :)